# Check if the value exists in a dropdown

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a dropdown that contains Subjects.

What I did, I use the code below to get the values on that dropdown.

```
IList<IWebElement> allOptions = check.Options;
```

Then I declare a string that will handle all the values I have to verify if these values exist on that dropdown.

```
string[] subject = "Math", "Science", "History", "Calculus", etc...
```

I loop them to get how many subjects I have to check if they exist on the dropdown then verify it using Contains.

```
if (allOptions.Contains(subject[i]))
                {
                    exist = true;
                }
```

However, I am getting an error that cannot convert a string to OpenQA.Selenium.IWebElement.

Anyone has idea how to fix it?

Thank you.

Comment: From where does "check" in the first lines comes ?
You're getting error because subject[i] is string and allOptions is IList<IWebElement> so you can't compare them !

Comment: check has the element name of dropdown.

Comment: sorry about that one. its 'exist' not 'subject'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use LINQ for this.  Basically this code:

```
if (allOptions.Contains(subject[i]))
{
    exist = true;
}
```

Can be replaced by a single line:

```
exist = allOptions.Any(x => x.Text == subject[i]);
```

Basically this code just checks if any element in the `allOptions` list has `Text` that matches `subject[i]`.  If true, `exist` is now `true`, if false `exist` is now `false`.

Comment: @Rufus Sorry, I beat you by a few seconds

Comment: i have to include this inside the for loop right? then it will verify all the subjects? I guess this is the closest one. I will try it and let you know.

Comment: @anonymousRey this code replaces your last code example in your question.

Comment: there's a little bit flaw in this code. If I have 6 subjects. and one of them is not present in the dropdown. it will still return the value of true because it will only get the last result. what if I included a non subject in the middle of my string[] subject.

Comment: @anonymousRey The code in my answer is a 1-1 replacement for the code posted in your question.  You will have to post more code/context in your question so I can adjust.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, you cannot do that directly. The `IWebElement` contains a `string` property named `Text`, which is what you need to filter on. Like so:

```
var foundSubjects = allOptions.Where(o => subject.Contains(o.Text));
```

If you just need to find out if ALL the options are found in the `subject` array, do:

```
var optionsAreValid = allOptions.All(o => subject.Contains(o.Text));
```

Alternatively you could use `Any` to determine if at least one option exists in the `subject` array:

```
var isThereAValidOption = allOptions.All(o => subject.Contains(o.Text));
```

Comment: This will find all the elements that match, but OP needs a boolean value not a sublist...

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Text property` of the `WebElement`. it may be work for you

Comment: `subject` is a string array. `string` objects don't have a `Text` property.

Comment: I used the wrong variable but I was trying to make the point to use the Text property of the  WebElement instead of the element itself.

Answer (score 0):

Try looping through the `IList<IWebElement>` instead:

```
int subjectCount = 0;

foreach (IWebElement element in allOptions)
{
    if (subject.Contains(element.Text))
    {
        subjectCount++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Additionally, I'm guessing your program could be done in a much more efficient manner, but it's hard to tell from the few snippets of code provided exactly what you're doing.

Comment: this wont work since the dropdown has multiple subjects other than the subjects I only need to verify.

Comment: @anonymousRey I'm sorry, but I don't understand your comment. Can you please clarify what you're doing?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand correctly your code, but the loop checks if the values in the dropdown are the present in the subject string.

Comment: @anonymousRey The loop I presented counts how many times your `IWebElement`s appear in the string array `subject`. @Bozhidar Stoinev's answer finds you each of the subjects that appear. @maccettura's answer returns a boolean for if it appears or not. @Robert Altman's answer does nothing. The fact your question is so unclear is why you have so many answers doing totally different things.